# Getting 415 Error: Unsupported Media Type as response while converting SOAP to REST service in WSO2

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to convert a SOAP Endpoint to a REST Endpoint using WSO2. While creating and sending the request in API Manager , I am getting 415 Error: Unsupported Media Type as response. Can someone please help?

Update : I have taken the WIRE Logs and below is the debug

```
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,216] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,216] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "443[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,217] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSSMService"><soapenv:Body><web:QUERYUSERMAINT_IOFS_REQ><web:FCUBS_HEADER><web:FUNCTIONID>2gg</web:FUNCTIONID><web:SOURCE_USERID>ggg</web:SOURCE_USERID><web:ACTION>234</web:ACTION><web:ENTITY/><web:MODULEID>gg</web:MODULEID><web:MSGSTAT>ggg</web:MSGSTAT><web:PASSWORD>234</web:PASSWORD><web:MULTITRIPID>234</web:MULTITRIPID><web:MSGID>ggg</web:MSGID><web:SERVICE>ggg</web:SERVICE><web:SNAPSHOTID>gg</web:SNAPSHOTID><web:OPERATION>234</web:OPERATION><web:SOURCE>gg</web:SOURCE><web:SOURCE_OPERATION>gg</web:SOURCE_OPERATION><web:CORRELID>gg</web:CORRELID><web:DESTINATION>ggggg</web:DESTINATION><web:BRANCH>gg</web:BRANCH><web:UBSCOMP>gg</web:UBSCOMP><web:USERID>FCUBS</web:USERID></web:FCUBS_HEADER><web:FCUBS_BODY><web:USR-IO><web:ALERTS_ON_HOME>gg</web:ALERTS_ON_HOME><web:DASHBOARD_REQD>FCUBS</web:DASHBOARD_REQD><web:USRID>gg</web:USRID></web:USR-IO></web:FCUBS_BODY></web:QUERYUSERMAINT_IOFS_REQ></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,217] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "0[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,217] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 << "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,369] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,370] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "Date: Wed, 07 Jul 2021 08:37:17 GMT[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,371] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,371] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: a5d4445f-1bb3-4a74-8fe4-444f37d101af-000004e4[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,372] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "X-ORACLE-DMS-RID: 0[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,373] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,374] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "0000[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,375] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-7 >> "[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,382] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-12 << "HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,383] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-12 << "activityid: 3400c7fd-005b-4a12-9934-24dadddd56c0[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,384] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-12 << "Access-Control-Expose-Headers: [\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,388] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-12 << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *[\r][\n]"
TID: [-1] [] [2021-07-07 14:07:17,390] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} - HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-12 << "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more and give some samples of your API? Are you using API Manager? If, yes can you share the version as well?. Can you also share the WSDL (a mock maybe) which you have tried to create the REST APIs. Further, please check whether you are invoking the REST Resource with correct HTTP Verbs (GET, POST)

Comment: Thanks for answering, Yes, I am using API Manager 4.0.0 . WSDL can be accessed via : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YiAxX1qEqjWc1KQLyseIp-18InugOTMS/view?usp=sharing . Im trying to access the /queryUserMaintIO method and using POST. Hope this information is sufficient. Response Body I get is {
  "binary": null
}  and Response Headers is  content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Comment: Unfortunately, the shared WSDL is not working for me. However, re-verify whether you are sending the payloads as expected with the correct set of Content-Type. Also, check whether the response is received from the Backend service itself. You can enable the WIRE logs in the API Manager and check those.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. However I am very new to WSO2. Can you please tell me where can i set this Content-Type in the request? In the API Manager, I just use the Try-out option and it gives me the JSON expecting some values to be entered. Once I enter the values and click on execute, it straight away gives me the 415 code. And yes, I am getting a response on the backend service if i try on SOAPUI. Also, please let me know how to enable these WIRE logs and will it write in repository\logs directory?

Comment: Update : I have enabled the WIRE Logs and updated the description with the debugs.

Comment: Thank you for the logs. However, the logs are missing the initial portion. Can you share the complete WIRE logs? Also, can you share the complete request that you are trying from the SOAPUI. We can compare the requests dispatched from API Manager and the SOAPUI and add missing headers to make it work. Also, in addition, you can also try setting the `Disable Chunking` property as `true` in the in-sequence of the Resource.

Comment: Please find the complete Logs here :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jRMuaLqrg6N-aarBdlDdjhQViUjslJQ2/view?usp=sharing                                                                              Request msg from soap and API manager : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x0_XioNUHB_l5BNXhHomj-YNl82RAysw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In addition after checking the WIRE logs, i can see "Content-Type: application/soap+xml[\r][\n]" . would that be a possible cause? shouldn't it be application/xml ?

Comment: Yes, the difference in the `Content-Type` can be a cause for this behavior. You can simply update your SOAPUI request with this `Content-Type` and verify whether the Oracle Backend is throwing the same. If yes, we have to update the Content-Type accordingly in the API Manager.

Comment: I have tried to add the Content-Type in SOAPUI Request but it gives me other errors :                                                                                               <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns0:Fault xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>ns0:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer</faultstring>
      </ns0:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

Comment: However, in the raw response of soap , I see Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8

Comment: Please let me know how to change the Content Type to text/xml in API Manager. I will try that and see.

Comment: I have tried going to Resources and adding Content-Type as a custom Header Parameter Type and passed 'text/xml' but in the logs it still shows '"Content-Type: application/soap+xml'

Comment: You may find a property called `messageType` at the bottom of each Resource's in-mediation section. Change that to `text/xml`. This will automatically build the payload and changes the Content-Type to respective.

Comment: Thanks for the details, although after going to the In-mediation and changing the value of messageType, it saves, but when i go and re-open the in-mediation again, the value gets re-setted to what it was earlier. (application/soap+xml in my case). These changes are done using the admin user. Is there any other place where I need to change it or some other file is overriding this change?

Comment: Changing the `messageType` from the Resources section is sufficient. If it is not changing, it may be a bug. Please create a Git issue at the `Product-APIM` repo.

Comment: Thanks, as suggested, I have raised a GIT issue at product-APIM repo. I can try checking if this issue persists in the below versions of API Manager. I will keep you updated. Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: Another question, in wso2am-4.0.0\repository\conf\axis2 these files axis2.xml, axis2_blocking_client.xml , axis2_client.xml contain                              <messageFormatter contentType="text/xml"
                              class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
    <messageFormatter contentType="application/soap+xml"
        class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>  . I have tried to remove and comment application/soap+xml just to check but after restarting the server it goes back to the original state. Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: From API Manager 3.0.0 onwards, it uses a centralized configuration file called `deployment.toml`. So, if you want to configure the API Manager, you have to configure the `TOML` and during the startup, it will fill and configure other XMLs automatically. Making any direct changes to the XML will be overridden by the server startup if the configurations are not presented in the `deployment.toml`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Can you please let me know the parameter name in the deployment.toml file so that the configuration files from wso2am-4.0.0\repository\conf\axis2 are reset during server startup? I can try changing the axis2.xml file as a temporary workaround.

Comment: You can learn more about the new configuration model and how to configure the `TOML` in [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/understanding-the-new-configuration-model/)

Comment: Thanks for the details, I have tried to change the value of messageType to text/xml in version 3.2.0 in API Manager and it worked, although the soap headers and body <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSSMService">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body> are not coming in the request and hence it is failing. Any insights on how to add these soap headers to the existing request when it is text/xml?

Comment: Can you please help?

Comment: Sorry missed this. Can you recheck the Raw SOAPUI (direct) request and see what is the Content-Type sent from there (for the working scenario)? We can add the same Content-Type value to the `messageType` in the mediation sequence and recheck the behavior. Further, you can also enhance the `PayloadFactory` mediator in that particular resource's in-sequence add additional headers and elements.

Comment: Thanks Athiththan. the Content-Type sent to raw SOAPUI is "text/xml". Although, when I am sending the request from WSO2, it comes as "application/soap+xml". Now in the in mediation if i set messageType to "text/xml", my request message gets created without any SOAP Headers (E.g., <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSSMService"><soapenv:Body>)  . I believe that is the reason they are adding soap+xml so that SOAP headers are generated.

Comment: I would like to know how to set messageType to "text/xml" and generate the SOAP Headers. In-mediation File is placed here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HHSVkKFjsndeaCFq4knxv_Z6VN-kb68s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: WSO2 builds the payload with and without SOAPEnv based on the messageType that we are using. If you are Backend is expecting the payload with `SOAPEnv` and the `Content-Type` as `text/xml`, you can use the following property at the end of the in-sequence to change the Content-Type Header value: `<property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" />`. This will build the payload with SOAPEnv and send the Content-Type header as `text/xml` to your backend. The proposed property mediator should be placed after the `messageType` property in the sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the details, @Athiththan . <property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2" /> worked perfectly. SOAP has accepted the request, although in the response body i am getting **{
  "Envelope": {
    "Body": {
      "QUERYUSERMAINT_IOFS_RES": {
        "@nil": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}**  There is no failure in the wire debugs but I am not getting the proper response that I get in SOAP UI. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You can do a cross-verification between the API Manager and the SOAPUI Request body and the headers to see what is missing and anything sent additionally. Also, you can try changing the SOAPUI request as the same as what API Manager dispatched (by looking from the WIRE logs), and change that and verify whether you are experiencing the same or not. There can be a possibility that the Oracle service might be in a need of a Header that is missing when invoking through WSO2.

Comment: Hi @Athiththan, thanks for these valuable feedback and tips. I have tried it out and it works perfectly fine now and I am getting the response from the oracle service in WSO2. Issue was WSO2 was adding an extra ADDL tag in the request which was not accepted by the oracle service. I removed it from the request as well as the in-mediation file of the method and it worked. thanks for you're help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`415` Status code is thrown when the Content-Type and the payloads are mismatched. As per the shared `WIRE` logs, the `415` status code is populated from your actual Oracle Backend Server.

To verify what is causing this behavior, you can cross-check the Request sent out from the `API Manager` along with the SOAPUI Request to validate and verify whether there are any mismatches in the Headers or the Payload. Once verified, make the same changes to the SOAP to REST API Resource's in-mediation sequence to achieve the same.

Hope this instructions will help you to troubleshoot the behavior and fix it.